# Modify NLTK word_tokenize to prevent tokenization of parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have the following `main.py`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import nltk
import string
import sys
for token in nltk.word_tokenize(''.join(sys.stdin.readlines())):
    #print token
    if len(token) == 1 and not token in string.punctuation or len(token) > 1:
        print token
```

The output is the following.

```
./main.py <<< 'EGR1(-/-) mouse embryonic fibroblasts'
EGR1
-/-
mouse
embryonic
fibroblasts
```

I want to slightly change the tokenizer so that it will recognize `EGR1(-/-)` as one token (without any other changes). Does anybody know if there is a such way to slighly modify the tokenizer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default `word_tokenize()` function in `NLTK` is [TreebankWordTokenizer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py) that is based on a sequence of regex substitution.

More specifically, when it comes to adding spaces between parenthesis, the `TreebankWordTokenizer` uses this regex substitutions:

```
PARENS_BRACKETS = [
    (re.compile(r'[\]\[\(\)\{\}\<\>]'), r' \g<0> '),
    (re.compile(r'--'), r' -- '),
]

for regexp, substitution in self.PARENS_BRACKETS:
    text = regexp.sub(substitution, text)
```

For example:

```
import re

text = 'EGR1(-/-) mouse embryonic fibroblasts'

PARENS_BRACKETS = [
    (re.compile(r'[\]\[\(\)\{\}\<\>]'), r' \g<0> '),
    (re.compile(r'--'), r' -- '),
]

for regexp, substitution in PARENS_BRACKETS:
    text = regexp.sub(substitution, text)

print text
```

[out]:

```
EGR1 ( -/- )  mouse embryonic fibroblasts
```

So going back to "hacking" the NLTK `word_tokenize()` function, you can try something like this to cancel the effects of the `PARENS_BRACKETS` substitutions:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.PARENS_BRACKETS = []
>>> text = 'EGR1(-/-) mouse embryonic fibroblasts'
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(text)
['EGR1(-/-)', 'mouse', 'embryonic', 'fibroblasts']
```